# Building SOAP body with native php client

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am creating an soap client with php, I have successfully added the header and invoked the service.

my problem is my api responded with

> Application error has occurred, please review your request and try
>   again.

I used the

```
htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest())
```

to compare with the outgoing XML and expected xml, then I found following

outgoing

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:ping/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

expected

```
<S:Body>
    <ns3:ping xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/example" xmlns:ns3="http://example.core.engine.tflip.uua.com/">
        <arg0>
            <ns2:token>Wed Apr 06 01:19:24 IST 2016</ns2:token>
        </arg0>
    </ns3:ping>
</S:Body>
```

it is clear I am sending a null body, but I don't know how to create these because I am using

```
$params = array(
          "token" => 'Wed Apr 06 01:19:24 IST 2016'
        );
$result = $client->__soapCall("ping", array($params));
```

to call the service, I need to create the above structure and also have to add those namespaces for those nodes.

Also please suggest me whether it will cause any problems in defining  instead of

Please help me on this.

Comment: use `$result = $client->__soapCall("ping", $params);` because $params is already array

Comment: @LukaSvalina yes that is already an array, but changing that won't be helpful. inside __soapCall i need to pass an array only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution which works for me at-least just posting if anyone in need.

With all the security headers, I created the soap client and included the class which accepts the username and the password. and It turned out that the wsdl it self handled the name space for the ping method.

so my code goes like this.

craeted the soap client with the wsdl and made it traceable so that i can use the htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()); and  htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse()); to check my request and response xml. Note the htmlentities() has been used to make it visible in the browser.

```
$client = new SoapClient("--the wsdl link--", array('trace' => 1));
```

Also setting the soap header with the class WsseAuthHeader where I am initiating all the authentication and the headers required for the service. WsseAuthHeader class extends the SoapHeader.

```
$client->__setSoapHeaders(Array(new WsseAuthHeader("username", "password")));
```

With the created $client invoking the ping method (operation) in service with the expected values.

```
$response = $client->ping(array('arg0'=>array('token'=>'test','timestamp'=>(new DateTime())->format('Y.m.d H:i:s'))));
```

finally can do the echo to test the output with the

```
echo htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse());
```

Hope this helps, and special thanks for @Marcel for his support.

Answer (score 3):

The PHP SoapClient is a bit confusing sometimes. The easiest way is to work with objects. The following example is untestet.

```
class Ping {
    protected $arg0;

    public function setArg(SoapVar $oArg0) {
        $this->arg0 = $oArg;
    }

    public function encode() {
        return new SoapVar(
            $this,
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
            null,
            null,
            'ping',
            'http://example.core.engine.tflip.uua.com/'
        }
    }
}

class Arg {
    protected $token;

    public function getToken() {
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function setToken($oToken) {
        if (!($oToken instanceof SoapVar)) {
            $oToken = new SoapVar(
                $oToken,
                XSD_STRING,
                null,
                null,
                'token',
                'http://www.example.com/example'
            );
        }

        $this->token = $oToken;
    }

    public function encode() {
        return new SoapVar(
            $this, 
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
            null,
            null,
            'arg0'
        );
    }
}

try {
    // init your soap client with wsdl
    $oClient = new SoapClient(...);

    // init your arg object
    $oArg = new Arg();
    $oArg->setToken('Wed Apr 06 01:19:24 IST 2016');
    $oArgEncoded = $oArg->encode();

    // init the ping object
    $oPing = new Ping();
    $oPing->setArg($oArgEncoded);
    $oPingEncoded = $oPing->encode();

    // call the ping method with soap encoded arg object
    $oResult = $oClient->ping($oPingEncoded);
} catch (SoapFault $oSoapFault) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($oSoapFault);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

First of all we have our arg object with the token member and getters and setters. The encode function gives the arg object as a SoapVar object fully encoded. So you can call the ping method of the websercive directly with the soap client.

Comment: thank you for the beautiful code and the explanation, tried it but no help still the ping method has null value. to be more specific, what I did was I included all those function and the try-catch part inside one class which I already have, and changed all object to $this->. can you please tell me what value will be goes for the $this in (return new SoapVar($this, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'arg0');) line in Arg class?

Comment: try {
            $client = new SoapClient('my WSDL Initiations');          $client->__setSoapHeaders('my headers confg');

            //$oArg = new Arg(); //commented obj creation
            $this->setToken('Wed Apr 06 01:19:24 IST 2016');
            $oArgEncoded = $this->encode();

            $oResult = $client->ping($oArgEncoded);
            echo 'Request : <br/>'.
          htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest());
        } catch (SoapFault $oSoapFault) {
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump();
            echo "</pre>";
        }

Comment: No actually.. "My Fault" it must be a separate class... now its sending the proper request... though still same issue... code is sending the arg0 as an xi:type but in the expected xml it is an <arg0> will this an issue??

Comment: Hello Darshan, sorry for the late reply. There was a failure in my code. I 'm sorry for that. I 've edited the encode method. The parameters were wrong so it was obviously right, the the arg node got a xsi type. The SoapVar object expects the fifth parameter as the node name. Have a look at the edited code.

Comment: thanks again for the solution, though still I am not getting that <arg0>, instead getiing [ <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:ping><ns1:token>Wed Apr 06 01:19:24 IST 2016</ns1:token></ns2:ping></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope> ] , any suggestions

Comment: It 's just a guess. But does it help, if you use the Ping object I 've edited in my code example?

Comment: and one more doubt, in the expected xml message its ask for <S:Body> but the one I create goes as <SOAP-ENV:Body> will this an issue? also I am sending a security header as well which is accepted by the API.. which means my request is going through, only problem is with the body... please give me a suggestion Marcel..

Comment: The prefixes for namespaces are usually not relevant. The SOAP-ENV prefix is as good as the S prefix. It should be accepted by the webservice.

Comment: Thank you for the support Marcel! sorted out the problem and my API required 1 more input which they didn't document after their support call I figured it out.